# How to make "fit-content" take take full width? (CSS)

Tags: html, css

I'm designing a hybrid mobile app and I have a simple form that has a clickable icon inside it. For the icon to stay always in the same place, regardless of screen sizes, someone suggested I added the property `width: fit-content`. This makes the icon stay where it's supposed to stay. However, now my form doesn't take 100% width anymore. If I change `width: fit-content` to `width: 100%`, then the icon loses it's spot.

This is what I need it to look like:

[image]

And I manage this width `width: 100%`
This is what it's looking like now:

[image]

And this is what it looks like with `width: fit-content`

Here's my code:

```css
.wallet-body {
  width: fit-content;
  margin: 0 auto;
  float: left;
}

.form-group {
  position: relative;
}

.form-group input,
.pin-input {
  border: 1px solid #2C2C2C;
  height: 48px;
}

.qr-scanner-img {
  width: 11%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 2%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="wallet-body">
  <form class="form-pagar">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="amount" class="form-control" id="amount" placeholder="Monto">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="IDuser" class="form-control" id="IDuser" placeholder="Email del destinatario">
      <a href="#">
        <img class="qr-scanner-img" src="img/qr.svg" alt="qr"></a>
      </a>
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-confirmar" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalConfirmation">Confirmar</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: It looks like you didn't include the link for what's happening with fit-content. I'd like to see that.

Comment: Hi Ben, the link is working :)  Nevertheless, here is a link to that image. 
https://imgur.com/a/bm6Yxap

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly you can use the position absolute for the icon.

Answer (score 0):

you should add `width:100%` for .wallet-body and .pin-input

`

```
.wallet-body {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  float: left;
}
```

```
.form-group input,
.pin-input {
  border: 1px solid #2C2C2C;
  height: 48px;
width: 100%;
```

}

### `

HTML :: Remove class from image and add in a tag

```
<a href="#" class="qr-scanner-img">
    <img class="" src="img/qr.svg" alt="qr"></a>
```

CSS::

```
    .qr-scanner-img {
    width: 11%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 2%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    text-align: right;
}
```

Hope will work.

Comment: This solves the issue of the width. However, by removing `width: fit-content` from the `wallet-body`, the icon moves around when I test the design in different screen sizes.

Comment: can you please share screen shot?